# List comprehension with dictionaries for models

Tags: python, reactjs, dictionary, model, list-comprehension

I have a class of Post I would like to be able to key into the comments whoms value is a list comprehension of a to_dict() method for every comment, my question is how do I key into each object in this list to get that comments data?

**Post model**
class Post(db.Model):
**tablename** = 'posts'

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
caption = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
picture_url = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.now)


users = db.relationship("User", back_populates="posts")
comments = db.relationship("Comment", back_populates="posts")
postLikes = db.relationship("User", secondary=likes, back_populates="userLikes")
def to_dict(self):
    user = User.query.filter(User.id == self.user_id).first()

    return {
        "id": self.id,
        "caption": self.caption,
        'picture_url': self.picture_url,
        "user_id": self.user_id,
        "timestamp": self.timestamp,
        "user": user.to_dict(),
        "post_comments": [comment.to_dict() for comment in self.comments],
        "post_likes": [user.id for user in self.postLikes],
        "likes_count": len(self.postLikes),
        "comments_count": len(self.comments)
    }
```

**Comment model**

```
class Comment(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'comments'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    comment = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)
    post_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("posts.id"))
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    createdAt = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True),
                        server_default=func.now())
    updatedAt = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())

    users = db.relationship('User', back_populates='comments')
    posts = db.relationship('Post', back_populates='comments')


    def to_dict(self):
        return {
            "id": self.id,
            "user": self.users.username,
            "user_pic": self.users.profile_picture,
            "comment": self.comment,
            "post_id": self.post_id,
            "createdAt": self.createdAt,
            "updatedAt": self.updatedAt
        }
```

**Mapping over a list of posts, for every post : **

```
 {post?.post_comments.map(comm => {
                                        <div>{comm.user_pic}</div>
                                    })}
```

**what posts looks like**

```
{
"posts": [
    {
        "caption": "Hammy’s got the crazy eyes. Get ready to be pounced…",
        "comments_count": 2,
        "id": 1,
        "likes_count": 0,
        "picture_url": "https://celebritypets.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/Hamilton-the-Hipster-Cat-instagram.jpg",
        "post_comments": [
            {
                "comment": "comment example",
                "createdAt": "Thu, 02 Sep 2021 14:04:43 GMT",
                "id": 1,
                "post_id": 1,
                "updatedAt": null,
                "user": "hamilton_this_hipster_cat",
                "user_pic": "https://i.insider.com/5654a4c0c2814477008b51d8?width=750&format=jpeg&auto=webp"
            },
            {
                "comment": "comment on first post again",
                "createdAt": "Thu, 02 Sep 2021 14:04:43 GMT",
                "id": 2,
                "post_id": 1,
                "updatedAt": null,
                "user": "DogtorLoki",
                "user_pic": "https://photos.bringfido.com/posted/2020/08/04/849663/loki-1.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "post_likes": [],
        "timestamp": "Wed, 01 Sep 2021 16:16:58 GMT",
        "user": {
            "biography": "Mustache Cat. Yes, it's real. San Francisco, CA. #AdoptDontShop",
            "email": "hamilton@aa.io",
            "id": 1,
            "profile_picture": "https://i.insider.com/5654a4c0c2814477008b51d8?width=750&format=jpeg&auto=webp",
            "username": "hamilton_this_hipster_cat"
        },
        "user_id": 1
    },
    {
        "caption": "If dogs are good for your health, then two unicorns must be MAGICAL",
        "comments_count": 1,
        "id": 2,
        "likes_count": 0,
        "picture_url": "https://static.onecms.io/wp-content/uploads/sites/20/2021/01/05/dogtor-2.jpg",
        "post_comments": [
            {
                "comment": "comment on second post",
                "createdAt": "Thu, 02 Sep 2021 14:04:43 GMT",
                "id": 3,
                "post_id": 2,
                "updatedAt": null,
                "user": "hamilton_this_hipster_cat",
                "user_pic": "https://i.insider.com/5654a4c0c2814477008b51d8?width=750&format=jpeg&auto=webp"
            }
        ],
        "post_likes": [],
        "timestamp": "Wed, 01 Sep 2021 16:16:58 GMT",
        "user": {
            "biography": "A Baltimore Pup+MedStudent Mom, AMC Top Dog Honoree",
            "email": "dogtorloki@aa.io",
            "id": 2,
            "profile_picture": "https://photos.bringfido.com/posted/2020/08/04/849663/loki-1.jpg",
            "username": "DogtorLoki"
        },
        "user_id": 2
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Use dictionary comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't accessing the keys the correct way ehh...['key']

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.